# .net Try Catch for sockets

Tags: c++, .net, sockets, try-catch

MSDN gives thus example for catching out of network errors:

```
MyData md;

try {
    // Code that could throw an exception
    md = GetNetworkResource();
}
catch (const networkIOException& e) {
    // Code that executes when an exception of type
    // networkIOException is thrown in the try block
    // ...
    // Log error message in the exception object
    cerr << e.what();
}
catch (const myDataFormatException& e) {
    // Code that handles another exception type
    // ...
    cerr << e.what();
}
```

I'm working on converting a patch of C code to C++ and am uncertain how to incorporate this code:

```
if (WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{

    fputs("\r\n WSAStartup failed", smtpfile);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
```

into the try catch block

new to C++, so excuse my ignorance. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nothing in the second block of code throws an exception, so it doesn't matter much where it goes with respect to the try/catch block. But that example in the first block of code is bad. It allows the possibility of `md` being accessible and uninitialized if  `GetNetworkResource();` throws an exception. A better example would `try { MyData md;
    // Code that could throw an exception
    md = GetNetworkResource();
} ` so that `md` will not be in scope should `GetNetworkResource` fail.

Comment: Also, calling `WSACleanup()` when `WSAStartup()` fails is very bad, especially if `WSAStartup()` has already been called earlier.  Don't call `WSACleanup()` unless `WSAStartup()` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use try catch in this situation unless you want to reuse the handling part for many such situations.

The closest to what you want to do is as below

```
MyData md;

try {
// Code that could throw an exception
    md = GetNetworkResource();

    if (WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      throw new myXYZException();
    }
}

catch (const networkIOException& e) {
   // Code that executes when an exception of type
   // networkIOException is thrown in the try block
   // ...
   // Log error message in the exception object
   cerr << e.what();
}
catch (const myDataFormatException& e) {
   // Code that handles another exception type
   // ...
   cerr << e.what();
}
catch(const myXYZException& e) {
    fputs("\r\n WSAStartup failed", smtpfile);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
```

Other than this you will also have to define your myXYZException class which will implement IException

Comment: The `myXYZException` handler SHOULD NOT be calling `WSACleanup()` at all. That was an error in the original C/C++ code.

Comment: oh yes, we can definitely identify what should be a better place to call WSACleanup() . I was just explaining the try catch concept to JTwine

Comment: and also implementing a custom exception class derived from IException is not always needed. If we can use any standard exception which matches the nature of exception and not already handled; then that can also do the job.